# Is it better UI design to allow users to type directly on a DataGridView in Windows Forms, or to have a separate form to submit data?

Tags: winforms

Is it better UI design to allow users to add input directly into a DataGridView, or to have a separate form to submit/edit data, which then gets shown in the DataGridView?

Which is the more common practice? Does typing directly into the DataGridView make the UI seem incomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting User to directly enter in the data grid is the common practice. But This also depends upon the type of data.

If you are going with typing directly make sure the fields have proper placeholders and headers